# Complex shapes using clip-path

Tags: css, svg, clip

I am working on clip-path, But this thing seems not very easy to me. Actually I need to test a custom shapes using clip-path. I have attached the image below of what I Want.

I have done this so far, But this doesn't seems near to what I want. Any idea how can I achieve the exact shape using polygon clip-path?

```css
.margin-0 {
    margin:0
  }
  .padding-0 {
     padding:0 
    }
    
    .clip1 {
        clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0% 100%, 100% 0);

      }
  .clip2 {
        clip-path: polygon(1% 50%, 100% 100%, 100% 0);
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid padding-0">
    <div class="row padding-0">
        <div class="col-md-12 clip1" style="background-color:#ff0000;color:#fff">CLIP 1<br>CLIP 1<br>CLIP 1<br>CLIP 1<br>CLIP 1<br>CLIP 1<br>CLIP 1<br>CLIP 1<br>CLIP 1<br>CLIP 1<br>CLIP 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row padding-0">
        <div class="col-md-12 clip2" style="background-color:#262626;color:#fff">CLIP 2<br>CLIP 2<br>CLIP 2<br>CLIP 2<br>CLIP 2<br>CLIP 2<br>CLIP 2<br>CLIP 2<br>CLIP 2<br>CLIP 2<br>CLIP 2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is what I need.
[image]

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/clip/  - Refer this.  I think this should help...

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy way without the need of `clip-path` and complex code. You only need one element and multiple background:

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  height:100vh;
  background:
    linear-gradient(to bottom right,red 49%,transparent 50%) top/100% 30%,
    linear-gradient(to top right,blue 49%,transparent 50%) bottom left/120% 40%,
    green;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```